# How can I add a facebook share button to a transactional email?

Tags: python, facebook, email

Each of my users receives a weekly summary graph via email and I want them to be able to share that image (hosted on Amazon S3 in a public bucket) to Facebook. Additionally, I want to be able to add a custom title and description to the image, perhaps as default text in the message body of the post.

It seems like way to go is using Facebook API's share dialog. But I'm not sure how to implement this given that I don't know what the full url of the links to the next weeks graphs are. The filenames are hashed. I also don't know if I'm overthinking this.

Here's the page I've been trying to figure out https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use your own share button/image and link to the sharer.php: `https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=[your-urlencoded-url]`

The title, description and image will come from the Open Graph tags: http://ogp.me/

Make sure you follow the guidelines about pictures: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images

Comment: What if I want to have 2 share buttons in the same email. How can I get the right thumbnail image for each image? Can I create two open graph image tags? If so how do I specify which share button it is tied to?

Comment: the thumbnail comes from the url, you can have as many share buttons as you want. you only supply the url, so just use 2 different ones.

Comment: link of first share button: https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=[your-urlencoded-url1] - link of second share button: https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=[your-urlencoded-url2]

Comment: I just realized that users wouldn't see much from the thumbnail and then they'd end up on a *.jpg url. I think a cleaner approach would to get permission to post an image to a users facebook feed. So that they can see the full image without necessarily clicking the image and leaving their newsfeed. Is this possible without javascript? Given that I am just modifying the html content of the email.....

Comment: sorry, but i don´t understand what you mean. the user will see the thumbnail when he clicks on the share button and the sharer.php url opens. or do you want to post a photo? in that case, you need to authorize the user with publish_actions, that´s pretty weird just for sharing an url. because you can´t even add the url that way.

Comment: just use the sharer.php as i suggested in my answer, and make sure to use a proper image. i will add another link to my answer.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. I want to post a photo. When users get my weekly summary graphs via email, I want them to be able to share those images to their facebook feeds. In this case it seems like sharer and authorizing user with publish_actions are both doable options but I'm not sure which is best. These images are located at xyzspace.s3.amazonaws.com/picture.jpg. I was concerned that the picture appearing on fb would be too small. For now, I will try using the sharer as you suggested.

Comment: well, sharer.php is for sharing links in general. if you want to share pictures and make them appear as real pictures on facebook, you do have to authorize with publish_actions and post it with the /me/photos endpoint. but that would be pretty annoying for users. i would suggest sharing an url and using the og:image tag with the images you want to share.

Comment: title/description are no problem that way

Comment: Alright the only concern I have is that I'm not sure how to add two og:image tags. I'm adding these og tags in the <head> section of the email body right? How would facebook know which og:image tag belongs to each sharer link?

Comment: take a look at the links in my answer, they explain how to deal with open graph tags. you have to create a separate page for each shared url, it has to be an absolute url outside the email.

Comment: This works, but after sharing the user is left on the web page:

www.facebook.com/dialog/return/close?#_=_
which is blank

Comment: sounds like a temporary bug to me. hard to say what´s wrong without the details, you should create a separate question on stackoverflow, including your code and a test page.